# New Relic Logging Mechanism

Tags: java, logging, newrelic

Is anyone using, in a production environment, [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) for application or server monitoring? It seems to be in the same class of Pingdom and Zabbix.

More specifically, what kind of logs does New Relic produce? Its [relevant documentation section](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/AgentDocumentation#logging) does not say much. Do they use (or are compatible with) a third-party tool (e.g., Apache Log4J), or do they have their own log format and patterns?

If there is any open source log example from this tool, please provide a pointer.

Comment: What do you want to do with the logs? The dashboards on the NR site are incredibly powerful for monitoring the health and performance of your application, but I wouldn't use them for, say, building sales reports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full disclosure up-front, I am a New Relic Developer/Evangelist.

The New Relic agents don't produce logs which you then would parse in a tool like Apache Log4J. The agent collects data from your application (trace details, database calls, etc) and sends that data to the New Relic hosted application. To use the agent, you'll just need to install it. You won't need to add any extra instrumentation code or configuration.

You then use the New Relic site to view and all the collected data, which you'll see things like performance graphs and slow transaction details. Unlike processes logs, you can get full stack traces and SQL explain plans for slow transactions.

The references to logs in the documentation are generally for troubleshooting issues with an agent.

****EDIT****
The Java agent can produce a log, starting with version 2.6.0. Turn on `audit_mode` in [your config](https://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-configuration) and you'll find the output in `newrelic_agent.log`. You can see a sample of the output in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3361966).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, you mean that New Relic Logs are too proprietary to, say, do some simple string parsing? Don't they follow a specific structure? Could you please copy-paste a sample?

Comment: Nobody seems to work with this format. Could you please share a few more details, based on my questions above? Does your answer mean that New Relic logs are not "visible" or saved anywhere, but fed directly from agent to the server (hosted application)? Thanks very much!

Comment: @PNS We added an audit_mode to the Java agent in version 2.6.0. This logs all the data sent by the agent. You can turn it on in [your config](https://newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-configuration). It logs to newrelic_agent.log, I put a sample trace in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3361966).

Comment: Thanks very much for the sample! I presume the format of the output is defined from custom New Relic patterns, or is it one fixed format?

Comment: The data collected in a full transaction trace is different than the data for standard counting/timings, so they'll have different log formats.